# Django overridden choices failing validation

Tags: django

I am overriding the choices option defined in the model, which is just a blank tuple.

Here's my models.py

```
#For assigning Ciena loopbacks
class Dia_Address(models.Model):

    order_reference = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    equipment_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, verbose_name="Equipment Hostname", help_text="Hostname of the DIA device.")
    subnet = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=DIA_SUBNETS, help_text="Subnet in which the DIA device requires an address.")
```

Contents of my forms.py, which overrides the model choices.

```
class Dia_AddressForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Dia_Address
                fields = ['equipment_hostname', 'subnet']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            #order_id = str(order_reference.id)
            dcn_address_handler = AddressHandler
            subnet_id = "94806"

            DIA_SUBNETS = ()
            NEW_SUBNETS = dcn_address_handler.get_subnet_data(dcn_address_handler, subnet_id)

            DIA_SUBNETS = NEW_SUBNETS + DIA_SUBNETS

            self.fields['subnet'].choices = DIA_SUBNETS
```

Contents of my views.py

```
def addDia_Address(request, pk_test):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    dia_address_form = Dia_AddressForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dia_address_form = Dia_AddressForm(request.POST)
        dia_address_form.instance.order_reference = order
        if dia_address_form.is_valid():
            dia_address_form.save()
            return redirect('order', pk_test)

    context = {'dia_address_form':dia_address_form}
    return render(request, 'orchestration/dia_address_form.html', context)
```

The issue I have is this form is failing validation. I am able to select the appropriate option from the form dropdown menu. Is there any way I can disable this validation for just this one charfield?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The form validation is failing because of the empty choices tuple on your model. Regardless of what you set your choices to in the form, the validation will actually consider what the model dictates - in this case nothing! Remove the empty tuple and your form should validate.

Comment: I deleted the tuple, but it didn't work.  First I got an error when the form loads. I passed in the tuple as an init variable, but it still fails to validate.

Comment: So your model choices is completely gone? Does your form still show the same error?

Comment: If I remove the choices from the model, I lose the ability to have a dropdown. It just becomes a free text field.

Comment: It will be by default but you can change the form field to be a ChoiceField and get your desired result

Comment: Ah, so use modelchoicefield instead of overriding CHOICES.